# Right way to do "const pointer to non-const" in D?

Tags: d

Ok, according to http://dlang.org/const-faq.html#head-const there is no way to have a const pointer to non-const in D. But there is a good practice: declare a field in a class const and compiler let you know if you forget to initialize it. Is there any way to protect myself from forgetting to init pointer field of a class in D?

Comment: pointers are default initialized to null and dereferencing that will result in a segfault (on most architectures)

Comment: Yes, but it is a runtime fault. I want a compile time fault which is cheaper (in development time) to handle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes:

```
void main() {
        // ConstPointerToNonConst!(int) a; // ./b.d(4): Error: variable b.main.a default construction is disabled for type ConstPointerToNonConst!int


        int b;
        auto a = ConstPointerToNonConst!(int)(&b); // works, it is initialized
        *a = 10;
        assert(b == 10); // can still write to it like a normal poiinter

        a = &b; // but can't rebind it; cannot implicitly convert expression (& b) of type int* to ConstPointerToNonConst!int


}

struct ConstPointerToNonConst(T) {
        // get it with a property without a setter so it is read only
        @property T* get() { return ptr; }
        alias get this;

        // disable default construction so the compiler forces initialization
        @disable this();

        // offer an easy way to initialize
        this(T* ptr) {
                this.ptr = ptr;
        }

        private T* ptr;
}
```

Comment: And this stuff is not in the Phobos? =) Looks nice. Is there any discussion or reading about this pattern?

Comment: http://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#Rebindable Rebindable *kinda* works this way, and we've talked about doing NotNull before which uses this basic idea too, but there's a lot of trouble getting it to work correctly with inheritance, so it isn't good enough for the standard library yet. But while it isn't good enough for general purpose stdlib stuff, it might be good enough for you! Besides, I think knowing how to implement it yourself is useful because then you can pick and choose just how you want it to work. As you can see, it isn't a lot of code, but there are a lot of options.